# how to run a method after given time without sleep

Tags: c++, winapi

In objective C there is a method called performselector which help developer to run a method after a time.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector

I need a similar logic in C++. I am working with winapi.

I could not  implement CreateTheread and WaitForSingleObjectEx since my method is not static.

Is there similar approach in C++ like performselector?

Comment: [C++ standard threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)? And there are always ways around the non-staticness of your member function by using a `static` wrapper function that calls the actual member function.

Comment: Why do you think performselector is not sleeping?

Comment: @stark so does it stop main thread? I dont think so.

Comment: @Some programmer dudeso maybe you guide me on how  ?

Comment: Why don't you do some research. Passing state to Windows threads has been covered thousands of times before.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where do you know that I didn t make any research on this stuff. If you dont want to answer don t comment please.

Comment: Any websearch will find the info. Where did you look.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I look where other guys look in stackoverflow, msdn etc. Sory I dont want to make a dialog. I just need help on these stuffs. thanks

Comment: Don't be helpless. Do some research. Type *CreateThread non static function* into a search engine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130431/discussion-between-mibzer-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: No. Let's not. Let's leave at that and let you do the research.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sory I didn mean to call you at chat, I just hit the link accedently. I will continue on research.

Answer (score 3):

Use a timer from Win API: (edited, thanks to @user2120666)

- If you use a GUI (which relies on user32 lib):
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx
- If your app is of console-only-type (just kernel32 lib):
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686796.aspx

And handle its message. Do all of it in the main thread. This is how Apple does:

> This method sets up a timer to perform the aSelector message on the
>   current thread’s run loop.

Comment: This answer relies on fact that user32.lib is linked.

Comment: The OP says "I am working with winapi" so he uses user32.lib or user32.dll

Comment: @user2120666 What's the problem with user32.lib?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do much of anything on Windows without linking to user32. In particular, you won't be able to get a window on the screen. So that is kind of a pointless comment. But um, if you absolutely had to limit yourself to kernel32, you could use `SetWaitableTimer`.

Comment: @CodyGray: User32 is GUI (again GUI) component. Why on earth must CONSOLE (again CONSOLE) app use GUI component, specifically message loop. From my point of view this overhead. If you need timer, use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686796.aspx.

Comment: @Ripi2: Winapi doesnt mean user32. Is 100% possible and legal run console app without user32, so your opinion based comment is inaccurate!

Answer (score 0):

use mfc and  override CWinApp::OnIdle function.